# Entity framework not showing in solution explorer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project, why entity framework is not showing in solution explorer . I tried to uninstall and reinstall Entity framework. but still same.

Comment: Where do you expect it to see? What do you actually see? A screenshot, perhaps?

Comment: Did you reference it?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - when right click project in that selection show entity freamwork. but its not show. with out that i cant do cord-first

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing using the package manager console, choose the default project where you want to install the package.

You can also do it in project level or solution level.

1. Right click on the project where you want to include entity
   framework and choose  "Manage Nuget Packages"
2. Search for Entity framework and clicks install
3. You will not see the entity framework dll in your project reference.

You can also install packages from Package manager console or by selecting

Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet packages for Solution

Comment: Hi, i install it using it. entity framework dll also there but when right click project in that selection entity freamwork not show.

Comment: I think you are looking for EF power tools. If you need this option you will have to install https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d. This does not come by default with visual studio.